# Object Reference Not Set error

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I select the datagrid1,it shows an error as

```
object reference not set
```

Please help me to solve. I am new in wpf.

```
 private void dataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.dataGrid1.SelectedItems == null || this.dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count <= 0) return;
            this.db = new DbAccess();
            string str = this.dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0].Item.ToString();
            DataTable dataTable =
                this.db.DataTab(
                    @"SELECT [SeriesNo], [SeriesDescription], [Instances] 
                      FROM   [Roamani].[dbo].[View_Study123]
                      WHERE[StudyUID] = '" + str +"'");
            string[] strArray = new string[4];
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                strArray[0] = str;
                strArray[1] = dataTable.Rows[0]["SeriesNo"].ToString();
                strArray[2] = dataTable.Rows[0]["SeriesDescription"].ToString();
                strArray[3] = dataTable.Rows[0]["Instances"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: exatly at which line ur getting this error?

Comment: getting error in if(dataTable.Rows.Count>0)

Comment: @user3592261:it's means your Rows is null and you are trying to check count

Comment: first check your query, check it returns the data from databse

Comment: when am debug,the first cell value seen in debug section,but datatable as null

Comment: database is full of values,but datable shows null

Comment: are you using EF in your code ?

Comment: What is meant by EF ?

Comment: what is this.db in your code ?

Comment: db is object of DataAccess class file

Comment: can you please check your query properly.

Comment: this is am using "SELECT [SeriesNo], [Instances] FROM [Roamani].[dbo].[View_Study123] WHERE [StudyUID]='" + str + "'"

Comment: can you please show me what is in DbAccess

Comment: public DataTable DataTab(string query){
 DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
 try{if (this.DbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed){
 this.createConn();}
else
    {
                    this.DbConn.Close();
                    this.DbAdapter.Dispose();
                    this.createConn();}
                if (this.DbConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    this.DbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, this.DbConn);
                    this.DbAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }return dataTable;}
            catch
            { return (DataTable)nul } }

Answer (score 0):

Replace your method with below mentioned method and change the conncetion string.

```
 public DataTable DataTab(string query)
    {
        string conncetion = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Temp;User ID=sa;Password=sa123*";
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conncetion);

        string str = string.Empty;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cnn.Open();

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); 
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn);
        adp.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;

    }
```

and still you getting null then try with this query

```
 @"SELECT [SeriesNo], [SeriesDescription], [Instances] 
                  FROM   [View_Study123].[dbo].[Roamani]
                  WHERE[StudyUID] = '" + str +"'");
```

here View_study123 is your database name and Romani is your table name